# Angular pattern matching routes

Tags: angularjs

I guess that [documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#regex-parameters) in angular JS is very very old and it doesn't work, because I tried to use pattern matching. This is the exact documentation from web site.

```
// will only match a contactId of one to eight number characters
url: "/contacts/{contactId:[0-9]{1,8}}"
```

This is my route

```
   when('/item/{item_id:[0-9]{1,8}}'
```

and it does not work for

```
 /item/924523
```

Comment: Where did you see this documentation? Link?

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#regex-parameters

Comment: That's for the ui-router, which is an additional 3rd party module. So unless you have it included in your page, and have a declared dependency on it, then it won't work that way in vanilla Angular.

Comment: and there is no way to use regex in standart router?

Comment: It supports a pseudo sub set of modifiers that might feel a little like Regex, but it does not support a full on Regex in the named parameters. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider